# Sync pictures taken to dropbox

Tags: sync, android, dropbox

I am using dropbox sync to sync of my phone pictures to the cloud (dropbox). Works like a charm. Only thing is that also want to sync the pictures I take to my dropbox folder.

Both the pictures I take as messenger pictures are stored in the map /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/ but only my messenger pictures are saved to the cloud....

Any thoughts on how that is possible and how I can sync my pictures to the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a "share" button you can use to send your photos to dropbox, you can use IFTTT or similar services to connect your phone (among other things) to dropbox.

Dropbox manages a certain folder on any device and I can't imagine it'd take full control of the emulated camera directory, so that's likely why you're not finding all of your pictures copied over. It's only getting some copied over from some apps that decide to communicate with it. You may have to copy/paste the images you're looking to sync over to whatever section of your phone Dropbox is in, if you're not looking to do it automatically.

If you're on android, you should have the option to bulk upload photos from media directories. There should be a prompt to allow Dropbox to get access to your media files.